# Windows Script (Disable NIC after sleep)

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, windows-10

I'm a Unix guy and I need help writing a script on Windows 10 that will do the following.

1. sleep 60 seconds
2. disable Ethernet1
3. sleep 5 seconds
4. enable Ethernet1

I don't know where to begin in Windows.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469340/how-to-disable-or-reset-a-network-adapter-programmatically-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
timeout /t 60
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet0" DISABLED
timeout /t 5
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet0" ENABLED
timeout /t 60
```